# How could I explain the skin properties of a species that can be either fully land dwelling, fully water dwelling or amphibian like?

Tags: fantasy-races

I'm working on a world for a miniature wargame, sci-fi/fantasy genre. One species will have the ability to live as fully land dwelling, fully water dwelling or like amphibians. I've given them both lungs and gills, but I've not yet gone deeper into how that will work. My main problem is that the skin of (most) land dwellers won't take kindly to too long in water, while the skin of water dwellers and amphibians will rapidly dry out on land. How could I make this work?

My basic idea is that some bodily function could change the properties of their skin, possibly connected to whether they are currently using lungs or gills to breathe, but I can't seem to come up with a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Why do you think you need to explain it? There is no requirement that you need to explain every detail of your world. In fact bad explanations can often be more distracting than no explanation at all. This is especially true if explaining the phenomena isn't integral to your reason for building the world (in your case to provide background for an engaging miniature wargame).

Comment: Unlike humans, who are notoriously naked apes, most mammals and birds are covered in fur or feathers. [Sea otters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_otter). [Land otters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_otter). Some aquatic mammals do indeed have specialized skin which resists water logging; but other acquatic mammals have furs which prevent the water from reaching (most of) the skin. Or look at aquatic and semi-aquatic birds -- they use a dual strategy, with some skin (mostly on the legs) resistant to water logging, and the rest of the body protected by their feathers.

Comment: @sphennings I guess you're probably right, and it is quite possible that I'm the one needing the explanation, rather than those who may eventually play.

Comment: @AlexP Good points. I hadn't considered fur. This is in its **very** early stages, and it just recently went from being just vague thoughts and ideas to actually putting something in writing.

Comment: one word, "waterproof". you are wrong about skin, the skin of most terrestrial amniotes is waterproof and can handle prolonged water contact just fine.  thermoregulation is usually the problem not damage to the skin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Almost Anything Will be OK**

As people mentioned penguins and otters are both fine for extended terrestrial and aquatic life.  Same goes for several species of toad.  The sea iguana in the Galapagos likewise does very well both on land and in the water for extended periods.  Even some fish can survive a certain amount of time out of water (hours mostly, but occasionally much longer) as long as they stay moist (usually via mucus membrane/secretion).  There are species of crab that live on land and in the water, and some full time land.  I can't think of one that goes extended periods in both environments, but as coconut crabs (the largest land-dwelling species) drown rather than suffer some sort of shell damage so I assume that's more a product of not having gills and air-breathing lungs more than anything else.  At any rate the aquatic crabs live on land quite handily as long as their gills stay moist, so give one lungs and it seems like it'd be fine indefinitely!   I can't think of an insect that routinely lives both in and out of water without pupating/metamorphosis, but even so that's the main types of "physical design" (fur, feathers, scales, skin, exoskeleton) taken care of with real life examples.

In the end I think extended survival of a species on land or in water comes down more to "can it breathe" than intricacies of the skin that are likely beyond the scope of a wargame.  If it's got the equipment to breath air and water the rest is covered!

Comment: You nudged my thoughts in a direction where they'd not yet wandered. This combined with the input from the comments, made me consider solutions/explanations I'd not yet considered. Inspiring thought rather than providing solutions is a really great way to answer questions like the one I asked here. I'll still wait awhile before accepting, but this is the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too knowledgeable on this subject but my first intuitive answer would be to look at something like penguins or otters? I know penguins are fine for months without going into the water, and they are also fine swimming for long periods of time.
Otters have special fur to protect them against water while they swim.

So if you are ok giving them feathers or fur both of these options seem realistic.

Comment: Otter like fur is one thing I hadn't considered, and that's a good idea. I'm unable to vote, because I've not yet earned enough reputation, and I'll wait a little before accepting. But definitely good ideas, that I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

**Slime coat.**

Aquatic vertebrates are slimy.  The slime coat protects skin from water and serves like second dispensable barrier to the environment.
Lungfish can transition from water to land and the slime coat helps with this, hardening to prevent moisture loss while on land.

Your creatures could be similar.  The are slimy and slick while in the water, and when out for any length of time the slime coat hardens into a cracked and scaly carapace.  They can regenerate the slime from their bodies to keep the coat functioning while on land.

These might be fairly thirsty creatures.

Comment: some aquatic vertebrates are slimy, many are not. slime is more often a defense against parasites than anything to do with the water itself in aquatic animals.